# Java Hibernate -Mysql Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, debian

I have a Springboot Java 8 application that connects to MySql 8 database.
The application calls an SQL view, which has a column, that have type TEXT. (I don't know why it gets that type, as it's a ~40 char long concatenated string, like the others that get VARCHAR type.). These fields in view entity declared as string.

If the application is deployed on 3 computers (2 windows, 1 ubuntu 20.04), all with mysql 8, its just works.
But on another Debian 10 machine, it writes these errors at start validation: `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [meossz] in table [bejovoszamla_tetelek_view]; found [text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [longtext (Types#VARCHAR)]`

I have no clue why the same application with same settings, with same version mysql (8.0.25) works differently on two machines. For windows machines, i just downloaded the latest from mysql site. For the Ibuntu machine where it works, i've installed from Ubuntu repository with apt-get.
For the non working Debian machine, i used the official repo.mysql.com with apt-get.

What's the problem? Why it works differently? How can i make JPA accept all SQL result datatypes for string field?

Comment: How is the schema created?

Comment: db script.  But all DB on all machines created with the same script.

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false to application.properties solved the problem.

But i still not understand why is this needed only on this single machine, while works without this on others?